# viusal studio can not find bits/stdc++.h on mac m1

Tags: macos, apple-m1

when i include bits/stdc++.h on visual studio i get "fatal error: 'bits/stdc++.h' file not found". (I created folder bits and file stdc++.h on "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1")

Comment: **Very** relevant, possibly duplicate: [Why should I **not** #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). `bits/stdc++.h` is not a standard header. It's an internal GCC, which will not exist if you're not using GCC.

Comment: so what i should do? i want to solve competetive programming problems, so i must have stdc++.h file.

Comment: Why is it that you "must have `stdc++.h`? Why not just include the headers that you want to use?

Comment: ok I solved this issue for others you need to create folder bits and file stc++.h here "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/"

Comment: That's very bad solution. Sure, placing a file named `bit/stdc++.h` somewhere on the include path will let you write `#include <bit/stdc++.h>`, but it won't actually work like `bit/stdc++.h`. You'll still need to include the all standard headers that you use.

Comment: for me it works fine.